# How to get the whole text from text edit QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtextedit

I am trying to get the text from a text edit and store it in a QString .

When I write this

```
QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
```

it only reads the text before the first '\n'
So how can I get the whole text with '\n's in it.

This is being called from a slot like this: -

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() 
{ 
    QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); 
    ui->label_2->setText(text); 
}
```

Comment: What is the text in your text edit? Does "line1\nline2" work?

Comment: no I only see line1 in the label

Comment: Saying \n I mean going to a new line (pressing Enter)

Comment: Is the label high enough, or allowed to expand vertically? If you print the `text` to the console or a file, is it also truncated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Make sure that the label is high enough to actually display multi-line text.

Comment: What do you mena high enough?

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev That it has sufficient height.